# Applying for another European tourist visa when you have a D type visa of another European country

Tags: visa

I live in Poland with an expired D type visa as a researcher-student. My visa was expired 2 months ago and I applied to rp for about 9 months ago! It is under process still! I dont know why this country is like this. My question is can I apply for C type visa now to another european country? Could it be multiple visa?
If I want to go to my country actually I need to close my file and then apply for visa. Therefore, maybe that can be a solution to get another visa. Extension of visa also has difficult procedure.

Comment: To which country do you want to go? How do you plan to travel there?  Do you want to return to Poland afterward?

Comment: Sure I am student. The schengen country which issues visa better.